# Euclidean Circle Geometry. Calculating the Radius

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

In the diagram below, DE is a chord of the circle that goes through c,d and e. A is the center of the circle. The perpendicular line from centre A intersects DE at B and the circle at C,

DE=100cm
BC= 10cm
AB=X

I need to calculate the length of AB / x.

Basically i need to calculate the radius of the circle without the diameter or circumference or anything. Do you have any suggestions as to how I would do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLUHR.png)

Comment: DB = half DE. radius $r = 10+x$. Solve $r^2=x^2+DB^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Extend $CA$ to cut the circle again at $F$. Then $BF=10+2x$ and by the intersecting chords property, $$10(10+2x)=50\times 50$$ Thus $x = 120$

Comment: Very good method. +1

Comment: @N.S.JOHN  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have $DB= 50$ and $AD=AC=x+10$

Now use Pythagoream theorem and find $x$